# How to change the color of a row based on the value of a specific field?

Tags: php, css, drupal, view, field

I've been using Drupal 7.42 to implement an inventory library. I have so far created a table view containing fields of a custom content type. The result is pretty similar to the one shown in the picture. 
[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVl5g.png)

I am wondering if there is a way for me as shown to color the rows based for example on a field which indicates the return date of an object. When this date expires the row should turn to red.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using `data-table` then search how to change row colors in `data-tables`.

Comment: what you tried yet? show your code here.

Comment: All the functionality so far is based on modules. I haven't added any code except for some html buttons. I am wondering if I can fetch the value of the field somehow, create a conditional check and color the row

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

1) give css-class to that column. so, in each row that column will come with that css class.

2) Include Jquery.

3) In document.ready({}): check for that column's each value and check if the date is expired or not and if the date is expired then you can remove existing class and add new class using jquery.

You can provide your html code to me.

Comment: I see, but could you please tell me ow can I manage to check each value as you said? How can I call one value?

Comment: Inside a for statement, operate on each row, get the cell value, compare with $.now(), add your custom class with .addClass().